# Heat equation with non-zero boundary condition

Tags: partial-differential-equations, heat-equation

I have the following PDE with initial+boundary conditions:

$U_t = - U_{xx}$

$U(x,0) = 0$  for  $x>0$  ,  $U(0,t) = 1$  ,  $U(1,t) = 0$.

The solution is for $0<x<1$ and $t>0$.

Is there an analytical solution for this PDE? I have tried solution by seperation of variables but it led me nowhere because of the boundary conditions. Thanks in advance